# Sieve of Eratosthenes in rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I am trying to code a sieve of Eratosthenes in rust. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), As I want to use the code multiple times I am creating a function to perform the sieve, however I have run into an issue. Ideally I would like to use an array rather than a vector for performance reasons as (provided the input value is hardcoded) the size of the sieve is known at compile time.

Is there some way of achieving something similar to:

```rust
/// get all primes up to max using a sieve of eratosthenes
fn eratosthenes_primes(&max: i32) {
// where &max is known at compile time
    let is_prime = [i32; max + 1];
    // logic
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not in stable Rust. When [const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html#declaring-a-const-parameter) are finalized, it will be possible using a generic parameter.

Comment: @Jmb const generics are partially stabilized. What you are talking about are [const generic expressions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560).

Comment: *"performance reasons as the size of the sieve is known at compile time"* - I am doubtful that you will feel any real performance difference. Or what kind of optimizations do you attempt that require this knowledge?

Comment: @Finomnis why don't you expect a significant performance advantage? my understanding is that Vec is held in the heap whereas arrays are held in the stack giving them a significant speed advantage in access speed. FYI I'm a fairly new programmer and most of my experience is in python so apologies if I have the wrong end of the stick

Comment: @Pioneer_11 Heap and stack have zero performance difference; they both are simply an access to the RAM. I'm not sure where you heard that from, but it's simply wrong. You might be talking about cache effects, but those exist regardless of whether the memory is in stack or heap. There is a small performance hit, but only for the allocation itself, which you only do once. And it's very small compared to the computation time of the primes. But for the actual computation it makes zero difference. But don't just take my word, benchmark it yourself instead :)

Comment: @Finomnis will do thanks. It sounds like I may have got access speed and allocation speed mixed up. I know rust recommends setting the size of heap variables where possible to prevent memory having to be reallocated

Comment: @Pioneer_11 Yes, that is true for vectors. That's why the `Vec::with_capacity()`/`Vec::reserve()` methods exist. Unrelated: note that vectors also don't shrink after you take items out again. If you want to reallocate to free up some unused memory, you explicitly need to call `shrink_to_fit()` on the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `max`, being a parameter, is not known at compile time. What you probably want is called [const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html).

Sadly, they are not fully stabilized yet. Specifically, [const generic expressions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560) are not stabilized at the time of writing.

So you can pass in the value and you can create an array from it, but you cannot do math with it yet (meaning the `max + 1` is not yet possible).

So what you can currently do is:

```rust
fn eratosthenes_primes<const MAX: usize>() -> [bool; MAX] {
    let is_prime = [true; MAX];

    // ... logic to compute primes ...

    is_prime
}
```

When using it, you often don't even have to explicitly state the number,
Rust can infer it from the output type:

```rust
let primes: [bool; 100] = eratosthenes_primes();
```

If course you can also specify it excplicitly:

```rust
let primes = eratosthenes_primes::<100>();
```

Comment: The downside of this is that OP can't call this function with an argument only known at runtime. I would thus suggest them to use a vector using the `Vec::with_capacity` constructor if this behavior is ever needed.

Comment: Yah, I agree :) see my comment under OP's post questioning if there actually is a real performance difference, because I am doubtful as well. But this answer was trying to stay as close to the actual question, and it explicitly only asked for size known at compile time.